# What is the equivalent of $0 in a Groovy script?

Tags: groovy

With Perl and shell scripts, the variable $0 holds the name of the file containing the script. What is the equivalent in a Groovy script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's currently available. See [GROOVY-1642](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1642) for a discussion of workarounds.